# Solving an Integral With Square Root in the Denominator

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Solve for k:
$$\int_6^{16}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^3 + 7x^2 + 8x  -16)}}dx = \frac{\pi}{k}$$

I have factored the denominator to obtain $x^3 + 7x^2 + 8x - 16  =  (x-1)(x+4)^2$
I think that since the answer involves $\pi$, I have to somehow make it look like the derivative of arcsine or something. 
Or should I do a trigonometric substitution?

Please help!

Comment: This exact same question was asked earlier [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751286/determining-k-int-616-fracdx-sqrtx3-7x2-8x-16-frac-pi)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As $x$ lies $\displaystyle\in[6,16] \sqrt{(x+4)^2}=+(x+4)$

Set $\displaystyle\sqrt{x-1}=u\implies x=u^2+1$

---

Alternatively,
Using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) start with $\displaystyle\sqrt{x-1}=\tan\theta$

$\displaystyle\implies x=\sec^2\theta$

$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x-1}(x+4)}dx=\int\frac{2\sec^2\theta\tan\theta}{\tan\theta(\sec^2\theta+4)}\ d\theta$$

$$=\int\frac{2\sec^2\theta}{(\tan^2\theta+5)}\ d\theta$$

Set $\tan\theta=u$

Comment: @Downvoter, please pinpoint the mistake

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine. We get the integral as 
$$I = \int \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x-1}(x+4)}$$
Now let $x-1 = t^2$. We then get
$$I = \int \dfrac{2tdt}{t(t^2+5)} = \int\dfrac{2dt}{t^2+5} =  \dfrac2{\sqrt5}\arctan(t/\sqrt5) + \text{constant} =  \dfrac2{\sqrt5}\arctan\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt5} \right) + \text{constant}$$
Now I trust you can finish it off.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $t^2+5$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Mike Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the substitution $x-1=t^{2}$ which then you will have the derivative of arctan in the integral.